# Replace a line if previous lines match

Tags: string, sed, replace

I'm trying to write a bash script but I'm currently stuck.

Let's say i have the following file:

```
targets {
        type = pppcfg_target_internet;
        name = "internet";
        only_crypt_auth = no;
        local {
                username = "";
                passwd = "";
```

I would like to replace the username and password.
The problem is, this section exists multiple times, except for the second line.

So what I would like to do:

Replace "**username**" and "**password**" if there is a "**type = pppcfg_target_internet;**" a few lines before.

Preferably, I'd like to keep it flexible enough that I don't have to set it to the exact line in case the code changes a bit or a line gets added.

So "If there is "**pppcfg_target_internet**" in the 5-10 lines above the searched string, replace "**password**" and "**username**".

I will be glad to receive any help. Also for the recommendation whether to use "ask" or "sed".

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to choose range of text between specific lines where you want to replace, like the following

```
sed '/pppcfg_target_internet/,/}/s/passwd.*/passwd = "newpass"/g'
```

This means, that between strings with "pppcfg_target_internet" and "}" find and replace string starting with **passwd** with the next string: 'passwd = "newpass"'

Maybe it would be good to create some unique block ending

Comment: Thank you very much! I hope you don't mind if i extend my question a little bit. Let's say that the string im looking to replace is in "FILE_A.txt" and i want to replace it with a string from "FILE_B.txt". How would i have to adjust your suggestion if im working in two different files?

Comment: If FILE_B.txt contains a single string, you can read it before. By default read command will read string to REPLY variable:

`read FILE_B.txt && sed "/pppcfg_target_internet/,/}/s/passwd.*/passwd = \"$REPLY\"/g"`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^[^\n]*pppcfg_target_internet/{:a;N;/passwd/!ba
        s/^([^\n]*\n){5,10}[^\n]*$/&/;Tb
        s/(username = ).*/\1"new user";/m
        s/(passwd = ).*/\1"new pass";/m};:b;P;D' file
```

Gather up lines between `type = pppcfg_target_internet;` and `passwd` and then substitute new user and password values.

N.B. The use of the `m` flag on the substitute command to assure the substitution only occurs for that matching line. Also note, that if the number of lines gathered is less than 5 or greater than 10, the collection is ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately, this one doesn't work for me.